# Ubuntu grub confusion

Tags: grub2

When I boot up my computer, it will load a blank grub menu that has a command line and no operating systems with a black background, I am on a windows 10(I have formatted the windows partition due to reasons I can not say, so I only have Ubuntu 18.10 operating system on it) computer and I have the BIOS settings (secure boot is off) set where the boot order has Ubuntu to load first. However, I still get the blank menu. If I go into my BIOS/UEFI settings and change the boot order first option away from Ubuntu, and then move it back to Ubuntu and reboot it will load the operating system list for the grub (with the purple background). Basically what I'm trying to say is I can not boot Ubuntu without changing my boot order first, even though Ubuntu is already set to first in the list. I would like to get Grub to work consistently on first boot every time without having to change the boot order

Comment: ok... what doesn't work and what does work? You might want to read what you wrote again. There's an object missing and you probably forgot to put a part of the sentence you had planned to put.

Comment: @tatsu I think I fixed it, I'm not too good on the Linux/Ubuntu vocab yet

Comment: ok, thats a tad better, but could you edit it to also include saying whether windows 10 boots or not, if ubuntu boots or not and what you do to acheive either. from what I gather you've manager to find a temporary solution but, as this solution takes time and effort and is not the optimal behavior others normally get, yo'd like to get a normal grub working once and for all. is that right? (please edit your post again)

Comment: @tatsu Sorry about that, fixed it again and yes that is what I would like yo achieve. I forgot to mention that I had to format and delete the windows 10 partition due to reasons I can not say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you no longer need the windows partition I recomend you first run

```
sudo apt install gparted -y && sudo gparted
```

and in this application make sure you no longer have any remnants of windows partitions.

If you find any delete them and then stretch your current ext4 patition to take all of the created space.

(make sure you keep the ~500Mb EFI partition (probably labeled as fat32), this one is the one your ubuntu has it's grub on)

then once you've applied all your changes, you may close out of gparted and run :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y boot-repair boot-info
```

this should reconfigure your grub. you may have to alter boot priority one last time although I doubt it.

tell me if this is a detailed enough answer for you or if you need more simple instructions.

Comment: After running the tools it also warned me that my boot files were far from the start of the disk (still having the same issue as well)

Comment: What you told me worked, but I also had to do a bunch of repartitioning because I had it very messy due to previous Linux installs and not deleting their partitions so I have fixed it and cleaned up my partition at the same time

Comment: ok. we could have noticed this in gparted and moved the boot partition in gparted first. my bad. at least it's solved now. :)